# Modal Logics Isomorphisms

Tags: logic, terminology

What does it mean to say that the different branches of modal logic (temporal, epistemic, etc.) are isomorphic? I looked for the answer on The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy, but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: See [here](https://eprints.illc.uva.nl/205/1/PP-2006-30.text.pdf), page 8.

Comment: It means that if you reinterpret "necessary" as "obligatory", "known" or "holds at all times", etc., then true formulas will remain true and false ones false.